# How to convert ActiveRecord::QueryMethods::WhereChain to ActiveRecord_Relation

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

I have untypical problem today. I have where condintion that takes block:

```
User.where do |user|
  user if Avatar.where(id: user.avatar_id).empty?
end.first
```

This returns me:

```
NoMethodError: undefined method `first' for #<ActiveRecord::QueryMethods::WhereChain:0x0000000c672f08>
```

Is there any way to transform ActiveRecord::QueryMethods::WhereChain to ActiveRecord_Relation?

Comment: Not sure what you're trying to do but `where` doesn't use blocks passed to it. Rails thinks you're doing User.where.first, which isn't valid

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should give you the relation for `User` where `User.avatar` does not exist, which you can call `.first` on

```
User.where(avatar_id: User.pluck(:avatar_id) - Avatar.pluck(:id))
```

Comment: be aware this leads to 3 db queries, not sure I'd do it this way

Answer (score 1):

I'd do it this way:

```
User.where( Avatar.where("avatars.id = users.avatar_id").exists.not ).first
```

Answer (score 1):

Shouldn't something like this work?

```
User.where(avatar_id: nil).first
```

But if there's a problem where a user might have an `avatar_id`, but the `avatar` with that id doesn't exist then you might want to do something a little longer

```
User.where.not(id: Avatar.pluck(:user_id)).first
```

PS: you can't chain a `User.where` (usually), instead you should do `User.all`

Answer (score 0):

You could use `.select` instead of `.where` in Rails 6:

```
User.select do |user|
  user if Avatar.where(id: user.avatar_id).empty?
end.first
```